# Hi can someone explain what this error means and what i can do to prevent this button?

Tags: python, selenium, button, element, stack-trace

**Background**
I encountered this error when I'm trying to click a button. However, the webpage would show that I am unable to press this submit button, then it will give me this error and stop running the programme. Does anyone know how to fix this error. I am currently using a CSS Selector to find the button. Does it make a difference if i use another method such as the XPATH method instead? Also, I have 100% verified that I have keyed in the correct element, while incorporating a `WebDriverWait(EC.element_to_be_clickable(slot_submit_button), 4)`. I only study python and selenium so i do not have much knowledge about JavaScript, so please explain to me in simple terms so that i can understand this issue.
Your help would be really appreciated!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\BBDCBOT\BBDC1.py", line 88, in <module>
    slot_submit_button.click()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="postBooking(this.form, 'b-TPDSBookingConfirm.asp?limit=TPDS', '', 'Please select a slot to
book.')" onmouseover="blueBtnOver(this)" onmouseout="blueBtnOut(this)"> is not clickable at point (118, 330). Other element would receive the click: <td class="bluetxt">...</td>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00743AB3+2505395]
        Ordinal0 [0x006DAE41+2076225]
        Ordinal0 [0x005E2498+1057944]
        Ordinal0 [0x00612C09+1256457]
        Ordinal0 [0x00610F48+1249096]
        Ordinal0 [0x0060ED0D+1240333]
        Ordinal0 [0x0060DB68+1235816]
        Ordinal0 [0x00603857+1194071]
        Ordinal0 [0x006259F3+1333747]
        Ordinal0 [0x00603676+1193590]
        Ordinal0 [0x00625ADA+1333978]
        Ordinal0 [0x00635168+1397096]
        Ordinal0 [0x006258BB+1333435]
        Ordinal0 [0x006023E4+1188836]
        Ordinal0 [0x0060323F+1192511]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008CCB36+1554566]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00974A0C+2242396]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007D0E0B+523099]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007CFEB0+519168]
        Ordinal0 [0x006E02FD+2097917]
        Ordinal0 [0x006E4388+2114440]
        Ordinal0 [0x006E44C2+2114754]
        Ordinal0 [0x006EE041+2154561]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76A7FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77097A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77097A6E+238]
```

Update:
This is the XPATH for the element: `slot_submit_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input[2]')`

This is the CSS Selector for the element: `slot_submit_button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="Submit"]')`

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated with the relevant HTML of the element

Answer (score 2):

This error means that element is present in the DOM but it is overlapped by some other element.

In your case,

```
<input type="button" name="" value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="postBooking(this.form, 'b-TPDSBookingConfirm.asp?limit=TPDS', '', 'Please select a slot to
book.')" onmouseover="blueBtnOver(this)" onmouseout="blueBtnOut(this)">
```

is overlapped by

```
<td class="bluetxt">...</td>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, however I'd like to add that it is at the point selenium tries to click that the element is overlapped by another. The element you're trying to click is not necessarily fully overlapped, but could also just be partly overlapped on the point you're trying to click.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Shukla, could I ask why such an error happens? Why would the element be overlapped by some other element? Will choosing another selector prevent such an error?

Comment: Hi @ToangarashiWoon, Sometimes when we try to locate element so element, even if present on some other screen, but still can be located however we cannot perform any operation on it. So such kind of exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

The Error means that the case was of web element overlapping. Here, Click was performed as per your code however, there was some other element present at that location which took that click.

Resolution by using javascript :-

```
button = find_element(By.XPATH, '<Valid Xpath>')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

The Way is to click it using a javascript code, which performs the click action on the first argument found matching the XPath.

Comment: This is a possible solution indeed, but it doesn't explain why the error occurs, like the OP asked to. Upvoted anyways, but try to include the explanation as well.

Comment: Hi @kumar Rishabh, could I ask what the arguments[0] mean in the driver execute_script line of code means?

Comment: It takes the first object matching the Xpath.